# How is this set of points linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology, simplex, simplicial-complex

> If $s_0 \lt s_1 \lt \dots \lt s_q$ are simplexes  in some euclidean space, then $\{b^{s_0}, \dots, b^{s_q}\}$ is affine independent, where $b^{s_i}$ means the barycenter of the $s_i$ simplex and $s_1 \lt s_2$ means $\text{Vert($s_1$)} \subset \text{Vert($s_2$)}$.

I can see that I would have to show that: $$\sum _{i=1}^q c_i(b^{s_i}-b^{s_0})= 0 \Rightarrow c_i=0$$

But for all $i \lt q$, $$\text{Vert}(s_i) \subset \text{Vert}(s_q)$$
therefore every barycenter $b^{s_i}$ can be written as a linear combination of vertices in $s_q$.

Therefore:

$$\sum _{i=1}^q c_i(b^{s_i}-b^{s_0})= c_1(\sum(m_i^{s_1}-m_i^{s_0})v_i) + \dots  + c_q(\sum(m_i^{s_q}-m_i^{s_0})v_i)$$ $$= c_1(\sum d_i^{s_1}v_i) + \dots + c_q(\sum d_i^{s_q}v_i), \text{ where $d_i^{s_j} = m_i^{s_j} - m_i^{s_0}$ } $$

Which can be rewritten as

$$(\sum c_id_1^{s_i}) v_1 + \dots +(\sum c_id_q^{s_i}) v_q= 0 \Rightarrow \text{ each coefficient $=0$ }$$

but from here I can't see any way to show that each $c_i$ would be $0$.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Up to an affine linear change of coordinates, you can assume that the vertices of the simplices are the origin, followed by the standard unit basis vectors in order; and that the $i$th simplex $s_i$ is the convex hull of the first $i$ of these. Then you could compute the barycenters explicitly. In particular the first $I$ barycenters all lie in the plane $x_i=0$, so it seems to me that the $(i+1)$st barycenter must be independent of them. Does that sound along the right lines?

Comment: I think you would have to assume they're nondegenerate simplices (or are they assumed to always be nongenerate)?  Otherwise, I would think $s_1 = \langle (0, 0), (1, 0) \rangle$, $s_2 = \langle (0, 0), (\frac{1}{2}, 0), (1, 0) \rangle$ would be a counterexample.